# Finding a subgroup of $S_5$ that is isomorphic to $D_5$

Tags: permutations, group-isomorphism, cayley-table

To find a subgroup, I calculated the entire Cayley Table for $D_5$ and looked for wherever there was an Identity. Then, I calculated my subgroup of $S_5$ accordingly.

I know that $D_5$ =

{$I, R_1, R_2, R_3, R_4, M_0, M_1, M_2, M_3, M_4$}

with the corresponding subgroup:

{$I, (123), (124), (142), (132), (12), (13), (14), (23), (24)$}

Now, I know this isn't correct because when I take (23)(12) it should give (142) [because $M_3M_0 = R_3$], but this is clearly incorrect. I know the last 5 elements must be transpositions because in $D_5$ the final five elements are inverses of themselves.

I was wondering if there was a succinct method of finding a subgroup of $S_5$ that is isomorphic to $D_5$ without going through a bunch of unnecessary calculations.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you conclude $(142)$ from $(23)(12)$?

Comment: This can't be right because there is no element of order $5$, and there are elements of order $3$, which $D_5$ does not have. I don't know why there is downvoting though.

Comment: From the subgroup that I made, the corresponding element in $D_5$ gives (142) in the subgroup, which is clearly incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$D_{10} = \langle (12345), (25)(34) \rangle \leq S_5$ (My $D_{10}$ is your $D_5$ - I prefer this notation where the subscript is the number of elements).

The full subgroup structure of $S_5$ can be found [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_symmetric_group:S5).

In order to construct this subgroup, the abstract group $D_{10}$ has presentation $\langle a , b \mid a^5 = b^2 = 1, bab^{-1} = a^{-1} \rangle$, so start by trying to find two elements satisfying these relations. For example, the first element must have order 5, and so must be a 5 cycle.

Comment: From your advice, I calculated the following subgroup:

{$I, (12345), (15432), (12)(53)(4), (54)(13)(2), (43)(25)(1), (53), (12), (15)(24)(3), (23)(14)(5)$}

However, I am still not sure how to check its correctness.

Comment: Try and explicitly define a homomorphism from $D_{10}$ into this subgroup, then show that it is bijective. The harder part might be showing that the map is a homomorphism using your description of $D_{10}$.

Comment: Informally, that $D_{10}$ has the above presentation is saying that it is the largest group  generated by $a$ and $b$ with $a$ and $b$ satisfying those relations. Therefore, an alternative approach (which can be made formal) is to take $a = (12345), b= (25)(34)$ and show these satisfy the relations, and as this subgroup has the same size as $D_{10}$, they must be isomorphic.